# Where to upload non-public user files in Symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

I am working on a Symfony 2.8 project, and I would like to ask users to upload files via a form. These files are not public (like a profile avatar or something), so I don't want to place them under `web/`, after uploading them only the admins are allowed to know the location of them and to open them via the admin interface of the site. Moving uploaded files near the source code in the actual bundle sounds wrong to me...so is there any official or recommended path to move the uploaded files which is still under the root of the project?

Answer (score 2):

If your requirement is that uploaded files should be downloadable by authorized people only then you must keep them outside the `web` root obviously. Any directory outside would be fine however they should be kept outside your codebase as well.

You could create `data` directory in the project root for instance. You can event mount a NFS/S3 share, that choice is yours to make.

To allow files to be downloaded you can create a controller which would serve files to authorized requests only. Example controller (PHP7 based):

```
final class DownloadController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/download/{path}", requirements={"path"=".+"}, name="download")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Security("is_granted('FILE_DOWNLOAD', path)")
     */
    public function __invoke(string $path): Response
    {
        return $this->file($yourUploadBasePath . $path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a `data` or `uploads` directory in your project root or if your server is nginx and you have control over web server configuration, you could use http_auth_request module:
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html

Then if you try to access the file, nginx performs a subrequest to your application and if your app returns anything else than 2xx status code, access to the file is denied.

The downside of this approach is that if you replace the webserver or have some error in the configuration, those files would be publicly exposed.